# Teams² and Microsoft: What data does Stack Overflow share with Microsoft?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, privacy, gdpr

This is about the "exciting" new [blog post on the integration of Stack Overflow Teams with Microsoft (Teams²)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/04/microsoft-teams-integration-announcement).

I would like to know what data is shared with Microsoft. Say I subscribe to Stack Overflow Teams, and then enable Microsoft integration. What data does Stack Overflow get about me, and what data does Stack Overflow give to Microsoft? Is it just the user IDs? Real names? Email addresses? Preferences? Login times? Etc.

I cannot find any mention of Microsoft anywhere in [the privacy policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy), and the ["Technical Deep Dive" blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/04/a-technical-deep-dive-into-our-ms-teams-integration) does not answer the question. There's a description about how the process works, but nothing about what data is exchanged.

The GDPR requires that there be an explicit privacy policy stating exactly what data is shared with Microsoft. Where can I review this policy?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'll answer technically since I'm not a lawyer - we don't share any data about you or your Stack Overflow Team with Microsoft.

When the app is installed by an admin of your Stack Overflow Team we store a mapping between your Microsoft Teams tenant ID & service URL and your Stack Overflow Team.

When a user adds the app (after installation by an admin) we store a mapping between the user's Microsoft Teams ID, AAD object ID & the conversation that is associated with the SO for Teams bot and your Stack Overflow account.

That's all we store on our end and we use it to allow us to interact with the MS Teams API. During use of the app/bot information about the conversation (including the text of the specific message that the bot was engaged in) is sent through our servers, but never stored *ever* - it's only used to process the current request and discarded when we're done.

The only time we send content from your Stack Overflow Team to your Microsoft Team is in response to a command that requires it (such as search or link unfurling) or when a notification is fired from Stack Overflow (i.e. webhooks).

Comment: Ok, so if I understand this correctly the sensitive data that is shared are the Microsoft Teams ID, from Microsoft to Stack Overflow, but Microsoft does not receive any data from Stack Overflow that they store that can be linked back to a person? That teams id is the "general team id" or a personal user id?

Comment: @Tschallacka correct regarding the direction of the data. There are several identifiers in play here - the tenant id for teams (this is general and identifies the entire team), a user id (identifies a specific user) and a AAD object id (also identifies a specific user). The last two are both needed because of quirks in the MS Teams API that needs one or the other. We have to have store something linking an SO account to an MS Teams user so that webhooks / notifications work correctly.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarifying. Is there something in the pipeline to put this in a privacy policy/teams privacy policy?

Comment: @Tschallacka product team is on the case, we're working with legal to get the privacy policy updated for these kinds of integrations

Comment: Nice. Thanks for looking into it and the explanations. It's much appreciated!